# Monad and identity element

Tags: category-theory, monads

There are 2 natural transformation are introduced in [the monad definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)):
$$ \mu: T^2 \to T $$
$$ \eta: I \to T $$

The following conditions have to be satisfied:
$$ \mu \circ \mu T = \mu \circ T \mu$$
$$ \mu \circ \eta T = \mu \circ T \eta$$
The first one is used for monoid associativity and the second one for identity presence proofs.

From other hand the $\mu$ definition gives us a binary operation $T \otimes T \equiv \otimes(T,T) \equiv \mu(T \cdot T)$ (monoidal product). The operation can be defined as $$T \otimes T = T.$$ I.e. from the definition we already have $T$ as the identity element. I am confusing why do we need the additional one ($ \mu \circ \eta T = \mu \circ T \eta$) to define the identity presence? May be I miss something critical?

EDITION AFTER ASKING:
First of all the question is incorrect and can confuse the readers. The following incorrect statements were made:

1. Natural transformation $\mu$ was declared as monoidal product.
   Really the monoidal product in the case is the functor composition
   but not the natural transformation.
2. The 1. lead to incorrect interpretation for $\mu$ acting on the pair
   $T,T$ aka $\mu(T^2) = T$. Really if we have a morphism $f_1: a \to b$
   and $f_2: a \to b$ then assuming $f_1(a) = b, f_2(a)=b$ leads to
   incorrect conclusion (that I made) about equality $f_1 = f_2$.

Comment: $\mu\colon T^2\to T$ is a natural transformation from the composition of $T$ with itself back to $T$. In particular, there is no monoidal product preset and I don't understand what you mean when you write $\mu(T,T)=T\otimes T$. The left-hand side has no meaning. It may help you to write down the components of the natural transformations $\mu $ and $\eta$ to see what the correct domains are. You may also wish to look at a particular monad, say Manes monad or one obtained from a free construction like the free monoid functor.

Comment: As I understood $\mu$ defines a binary operation for $T$. It has to be associative and has to have identity element to complete the monoid construction. My question is about the identity element in the construction: is $T$ the identity element? If yes then why do we need $\eta$

Comment: Your understanding is not quite right. I re-iterate my recommendation in my comment above in order to elucidate things for you. Have a look at Mac Lane's book.

Comment: $\mu$ is sort of a binary operation $T\otimes T\to T$, where $\otimes$ is composition. But it's not an operation that takes functors as input and gives another functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the identity laws are $\mu \circ \eta_T = id_T = \mu \circ T\eta$.

Next, thinking of $\mu$ as a binary operation is an unusual (but doable!) thing. Even taking that view though, what you wrote doesn't make much sense. Making an analogy to a normal, set-theoretic monoid, say addition on $\mathbb N$, we can show where you went wrong. $+:\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb N$. You then say something like we can define some operation via $\mathbb N\otimes\mathbb N=\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ or maybe $=+(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$ or something. This part of the question doesn't make any sense. It's both not clear how this defines a binary operation nor is it clear what you even intend $\mu(T\cdot T)$ to mean. The closest thing notationally for $\mu(T\cdot T)$ to mean would be $\mu_{T^2}$ which is not the same sort of thing as $T$ so $T\otimes T=T$ wouldn't make sense, let alone be true.

Thinking of $\mu$ as a kind of binary operator doesn't seem like a thing that is commonly done, but it can be done and is kind of nice. We can make a strict monoidal category whose objects are endofunctors on some given category and whose arrows are natural transformations. The monoidal structure is simply the composition of functors with unit $Id$. Every monoidal category gives rise to a [multicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multicategory) where, e.g., a multi-arrow $(F,G,H)\to K$ corresponds to an arrow $F\otimes G\otimes H\to K$ in the monoidal category. (To remove the restriction to endofunctors we can instead consider [virtual double categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/virtual+double+category).)

From the above perspective, $\mu$ is a multi-arrow $\mu : (T,T)\to T$ and $\eta : ()\to T$. The monad laws are then basically the monoid laws. $\mu\circ_2(\mu,id_T)=\mu\circ_2(id_T,\mu)$ and $\mu\circ_2(\eta,id_T)=id_T=\mu\circ_2(id_T,\eta)$. This can be made even clearer if we take a [doctrinal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrine#as_logics) view via the doctrine of monoidal categories. Then we get $\mu(x,\mu(y,z))=\mu(\mu(x,y),z)$ and $\mu(\eta(),x)=x=\mu(x,\eta())$ which looks exactly like the normal laws for monoids with $\eta$ as the unit.

Comment: I think that I understood the problem: I assumed functor $T$ as a set with one element only (the $T$ itself) but really it seems to be something that has a complex internal structure and as result the binary operations that I wrote did not make a sence